# Not able to access Javascript filereader in java class

Tags: java, javascript, filereader

How to access my Javascript `FileReader` in my Java class.
My HTML code is

```
<center>
                <form id="target" method="post" action="mod">
                <br>
                <textarea id="textId"></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="hidden" id="hiddenImages" name="hiddenImages" >
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form> 
        </center>
<script>
var imagePath="";
var reader=null;
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) { 
 imagePath=$("#textId").val();
reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
      var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    }
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(imagePath); 
imageMap.push(reader);
$("#hiddenImages").val(reader);
});
</script>
```

I'm creating the file reader and setting the value to the hidden field in my form.
In my Servlet i'm trying to access like

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
String val=req.getParameter("textId").toString();
FileReader files = req.getParameter("hiddenImages");
}
```

But it's giving compilation error like `change the files type to String`. How to access the value as `FileReader` or `FileInputStream`.

Comment: I think there's a bit of confusion in here: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to convert my image or file into binary values and send it to the server. I'm not using any `file-uploader` using simple `textarea` to get the file path.

Comment: Lots of problems here.  1. req.getParameter() returns a String; you can't force a String to become a FileReader. 2. To read uploaded files in a request, you'll go crazy if you don't use a lib like Commons FileUpload. 3. You need 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' in your form tag or nothing will work.  4. I think you're confused about the relationship of a Java FileReader to a JavaScript object called FileReader; there is no relationship between them. 5.In Java, you don't use Readers to read binary data; you use InputStreams. 6. When you read uploaded files you're not reading from a file anyway.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for your points. Is there anyway i can do it? any code example or docs?